# Why is my instant hotspot on Yosemite / iOS 8 inconsistent?

Tags: macos, tethering, continuity

Sometimes, instant hotspot works in a split second. Sometimes, it works after 30 seconds, and other times, it just says "failed". In all cases, the state of the Mac running Yosemite or the iPhone is the same. To fix it, I have to restart one or both devices. What is the factor that is causing it not to work so I can always just turn it on without guessing which device to reboot? Is it something with bluetooth?

Comment: From personal experience, but no technical data to back it up, it's how good a 3G/4G connection it's getting at the time. Poor connection, no hotspot.

Comment: Did you ever get any more details on this? I have this issue all the time and it happens regardless of the signal strength on my device. Restarting always works, but it's a real pain to have to do that every time. It'd be nice if I could narrow down the specific process...

Comment: Nope. It's still the same. I have a great LTE connection 100% of the time, and when the hotspot fails to work, sometimes turning bluetooth on and off on both devices works, but rebooting the Mac or the Phone always works. I still don't have a pattern down though. In the end, it's just easier and more predictable to simply turn on hotspot the old way which is faster, but feels stupider, than rebooting 1 or 2 devices.

Answer (score 1):

It appears this issue still exists on the latest version of OS X (El Capitan, 10.11). I was able to find this in my system logs:

`10/9/15 5:25:03.213 PM   sharingd[679]   17:25:03.212 : Tethering: Request failed (id = 5D648B94-FFEB-44B2-BC8D-E116CA674465, duplicates = NO, error = Error Domain=com.apple.identityservices.error Code=23 "Timed out" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Timed out, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f9cfaece050 {Error Domain=com.apple.ids.idssenderrordomain Code=12 "(null)"}})`

It would appear that there is some sort of connection issue with Apple's authorization servers (which it needs to validate the iCloud credentials). However, I received this at a time my iPhone had no connectivity issues (full cellular service).

Filed [a radar](https://bugreport.apple.com) (23058238) with Apple. I'll update this answer when/if I hear anything.

Comment: Any news? Also having this issue :(

Comment: Nope. :( Me too, and it's very frustrating. More people to open bugs, though, the more likely it is they'll take a look at it. https://bugreport.apple.com/